# alfresco - show issues list on to site page

Tags: alfresco

I am using alfresco 4. I have created a new site called test and trying to show issues data list into it as a site page. I have successfully added tab/page alongside existing links like wiki, dataLists, documentlibrary etc. But I could not able to figure out the way to show the issues data list content on to page. I searched a lot on google but did not find any solution. Can some one help me with this ???

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where are you trying to show it? What are you seeing instead?

Comment: Are you trying to build a custom page which shows the contents of a datalist (list of issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully added the page to site by following [this](http://edlovesjava.blogspot.in/2009/01/extending-share-3-adding-new-pages-to.html) document.

Answer (score 1):

To add the Data Lists page to your site, go to More, Customize Site. Then, drag Data Lists down to the "Current Site Pages" area next to Document Library. Then, click OK.

You should now see Data Lists in the site navigation. Click it. If this is your first data list, the New Data List dialog will automatically launch, otherwise, click New List. Select Issue List from the list, give it a title and description, then click Save.

Now you have a new Issue List you can begin to populate.

As you create additional lists they will show up in the list of lists on the left-hand side.

If what you want is a page dedicated only to issues, you'll have to use the underlying Surf framework to develop that yourself.